# Packing scala tuple to custom class object

Tags: scala, tuple-packing

I have a tuple

```
val tuple = ("Mike", 40)
```

and a case class

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

How can I pack my tuple to object of Person class? Are there any ways except this:

```
new Person(tuple._1, tuple._2)
```

Maybe somesing like

```
tuple.asInstanceOf[Person]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**tupled**

You could convert `Person.apply` method to function and then use `tupled` method on function:

```
(Person.apply _) tupled tuple
```

In `scala 2.11.8` and `scala 2.12` companion object of `case class` extends `FunctionN`, so this would be enough:

```
Person tupled tuple
```

**Pattern matching**

An analogue of `new Person(tuple._1, tuple._2)` without ugly `_N` methods is the pattern matching:

```
tuple match { case (name, age) => Person(name, age) }
```

Comment: I'd add this conversion as implicit function of `Person`

Comment: `Person tupled tuple` is enough. I'm using Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me in 2.12.12:
`value tupled is not a member of object ...`
It's a case class with companion object.

Comment: @MarkusAppel `Person tupled tuple`  works only if object `Person` extends `FunctionN`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414109/406435 . This feature is dropped in scala 3: https://scalacenter.github.io/scala-3-migration-guide/docs/incompatibilities/other-changed-features.html#case-class-companion

Answer (score 4):

Little "just for fun" version, which can be abstracted further. Of course with a little help from [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
  import shapeless._
  import Tuples._

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
  val tup = ("Alex", 23)

  val personIso = Iso.hlist(Person.apply _, Person.unapply _)

  personIso.from(tup.hlisted)
```

Comment: Nice, but `(Person.apply _) tupled` is really the right answer here.

Answer (score 3):

You could define an implicit that does the conversion. 
I use this in my parameterized tests to improve readability.

```
// Define adults with tuples
implicit def makePerson(in:(String,Int))=new Person(in._1,in._2);
// Define kids with triples
implicit def makeUnderagePerson(in:(String, Int, String))=new Person(in._1,in._2, new Person(in._3));

//create single person:
val person:Person=("Mike", 40)

//crate a list of persons:
//
//Remember to type the list, this is what forces the implicit on each tuple.
//                     ||
//                     \/
val personList=List[Person](
("Mike", 40),
("Jane", 41),
("Jack", 42),
// Uses the implicit ment for kids. 
("Benjamin", 5, Jack)
);
```

I love this lanuage.

Answer (score 0):

Scala 3 has first class support for the conversion between tuples and case classes:

```
scala> val tuple = ("Mike", 40)
val tuple: (String, Int) = (Mike,40)

scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
// defined case class Person

scala> val person: Person = summon[deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[Person]].fromProduct(tuple)
val person: Person = Person(Mike,40)

scala> Tuple.fromProductTyped[Person](person)                                                                                                                                   
val res1: (String, Int) = (Mike,40)
```